# Visual Studio Add Class opens Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi.  I have a very strange problem.  When I rightclick on my project in Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express Edition and select:

```
add->class->C++-Class->add
```

a window opens where I can open a html page in Firefox, and in the background is an error window which says that the navigation to the webpage was cancelled.

How can I repair my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem. I just set the default borwser of my system to IE and the create class dialog works correctly. Setting it back to Firefox doensn't broke it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can repair your Visual Studio by going to:

Start > Control Panel > Uninstall a Program" in Windows 7 
(or Add or Remove Programs in Windows XP)

Right-Click on "Microsoft Visual Studio" and select Uninstall/Change. There is an option for repairing your Visual Studio Installation there.

Pete

Comment: In that case I recommend that you uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio. I would also recommend that you scan your workstation for any existing viruses before reinstalling it.